# How can I implement the Ellipse WPF extensions?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

How can I implement it while moving the Ellipse extension of it?
That is, when the user clicks the button and moves it - changes the shape in length.

This is the example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you stretch ellipse this way, it stops being an ellipse.

If you want to do this in WPF, a generic method is replace ellipse with a custom shape. By modifying the control points of the path, you can build the shape you need (2 halves of the circle joined by a rectangle). Relatively hard to do, see [PathGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx) and [StreamGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.

Another, much simpler method, use [Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of ellipse, note it has `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` properties so you can make it look like circle, ellipse or a stretched ellipse. This is very simple to do but it’ll only work if you are stretching the shape along X or Y axis.